# How do I open another channel from one channel in Roku?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am able to use curl to get apps and the apps id from my computer in Roku device. And  ultimately, I am able to launch channels using curl from my local computer with e.g. 
*curl -d '' 'http://192.x.x.x:8060/launch/33739'* 
 but what I am looking for is doing similar operation where I will have a list of channels and then I should be able to open the channels.

In external Control Guide of Roku in http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/External+Control+Guide it is said that it can be done, but it doesn't have a detailed information how this can be done. So, can someone help me find a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "opening list of channels"? You already said you can get list of the channels (=apps) and you can launch individual channel by ID. And Roku can run only one channel at a time so you cannot start multiple at the same time.

Comment: How can I launch a individual channel by id using brightscript? That is the main concern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bit twisted but don't think there is simpler way:

- create `roDeviceInfo`, call `GetIPAddrs()` to determine IP of the box
- create `roUrlTransfer`, call `setURL("http://"+IP+":8060/launch/33739")`, then say `PostFromString()`

Comment: Good to know. What's does the id `33739` stand for? The channel ID? If so, where do I find that for other apps?

Comment: @thekingoftruth - it's internal-channel-ID, for public channels you can see it in the Channel Store URL of the channel details, e.g. for this example https://channelstore.roku.com/details/33739

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

[Nas Banov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/226086/nas-banov) answer inspired me to write an [article on dev.to](https://dev.to/umitic/how-to-launch-a-roku-channel-from-within-another-roku-channel-b6f) regarding launching Roku Channel from within another channel. I hope my post will make it even more clear on how to do this.