# How to use Deep linking in brightscript to communicate from one app to other

Tags: roku, brightscript

Is it possible to launch an app from other roku app by using deep linking?

I've read this roku's document
https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/External+Control+API#ExternalControlAPI-Deeplinkingtoachannel

but could not find the exact answer for my question. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021954/how-do-i-open-another-channel-from-one-channel-in-roku) made by [Nas Banov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/226086/nas-banov) . Combine His answer with the documentation you already provided and you will be able to launch one Roku app from another with Deep Linking params.
In short find out your device IP by creating `roDeviceInfo` and calling `GetIPAddrs()` on it.
Now when you have device IP, create `roUrlTransfer` and call `setURL("http://your_IP:8060/launch/dev?contentID=13234&MediaType=season")`
after that just call `PostFromString()` .
contentID and MediaType are Deep Linking parameters.

[Nas Banov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/226086/nas-banov) also explains what is "dev" in the `setUrl()` link, only with the different example(internal channel ID):

> dev - in `setUrl()` function is internal channel ID, for public
>   channels you can see it in the Channel Store URL of the channel
>   details.

I have made a [GITHUB repo](https://dev.to/umitic/how-to-launch-a-roku-channel-from-within-another-roku-channel-b6f) that you can check. It will not launch channel with deeplinking params by default (it can but you will have to replace request URL and add the one from this answer) but it will launch Roku channel from within another Roku channel.
Also you can check [my post on dev.to](https://dev.to/umitic/how-to-launch-a-roku-channel-from-within-another-roku-channel-b6f) for a detailed explanation.