# Can I still deeplink to another Roku Channel?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am trying to have my Channel install/deeplink another Channel. There are a million threads like this that use ECP. Like this one:
[How to use Deep linking in brightscript to communicate from one app to other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48542416/how-to-use-deep-linking-in-brightscript-to-communicate-from-one-app-to-other)

However, earlier this year, Roku changed their policy to disallow ECP within a channel.

> ... Channels may no longer include code in their channel application that is designed to issue any type of ECP command...

See [Roku Doc](https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/developer-program/debugging/external-control-api.md#launch-examples).

There are still apps with deep links on the Channel Store, so I wonder if I can still deep link with ECP, or, there's another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to deeplink with ECP as it violates the certification criteria. If you still want to implement it, one of the possible way is to keep the required ECP url somewhere on cloud/back-end server. Read it at run time, replace the required parameter and execute the ECP command through http request(using *"roUrlTransfer"* object).

Comment: thanks! I am not approving this yet as this still, technically, uses ECP.

Comment: @kaho, sure, I am also looking for some solution without ECP. If you come to know please post as an answer here. Will be useful for others.