# How can i Open my "Youtube channel link" from my roku channel?

Tags: youtube, roku, brightscript

I searched and couldn't find more than just opening youtube app from my channel
but i want to open "Myname youtube channel" link from My roku channel
here is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021954/how-do-i-open-another-channel-from-one-channel-in-roku) for opening another channels from own .

below is code for opening only app . so i need something like meta data to pass into the below code, so youtube should open direct my youtube channel not youtube Home page.
Thanks in Advance.

```
    create roDeviceInfo, call GetIPAddrs() to determine IP of the box

    create roUrlTransfer, call setURL("http://"+IP+":8060/launch/33739"), 
    then say PostFromString()
```

Comment: Don't have the answer to your specific question, but I believe Youtube's app id is `837` not `33739`. You can get the app ids going to `http://<ip>:8060/query/apps`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass some parameters with launch like below

```
create roUrlTransfer, call setURL("http://"+IP+":8060/launch/33739?contentID=VIDEOID")
```

Comment: I dont want to open a specific video . i want to open the entire youtube channel in my app

Comment: i dont think we can do that... it is possible only if the youtube channel have API to open individual channel

Answer (score 0):

```
appID = 837
ipAddrs = CreateObject("roDeviceInfo").GetIPAddrs()
if ipAddrs.eth0 <> invalid
    url = "http://"+ ipAddrs.eth0++":8060/launch/"+appID
else
    url = "http://"+ ipAddrs.eth1+":8060/launch/"+appID
end if

request = CreateObject("roUrlTransfer")
request.SetUrl(url)
request.AsyncPostFromString(url)
urlEvent = request.head()
```